# Already registered user is not working

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli-multi-query

Why it is showing a **blank page** insted of *SORRY...YOU ARE ALREADY REGISTERED USER...* when i am supplying the same email that is already registered.

**connect.php**

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$database ="dbpro";
$con = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password,$database);

// Function for passing query into database
function query($sql_query) {
    global $servername;
    global $username;
    global $password;
    global $database;
    global $con;
    // Check connection
    if (!$con) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    if ($res = mysqli_multi_query($con, $sql_query)) {
        return $res;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
}
// Function for getting Indian Standard Time
function ist_time() {
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
    $time_now=mktime(date('h'),date('i'),date('s'));
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time_now);
    return $date;
}
?>
```

**newuser.php**

```
<?php 
 require'connect.php';
 @$fname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['Fname']); 
 @$lname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['Lname']); 
 @$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['Email']); 
 @$pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['Password']); 
 @$gender = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['Gender']); 
 @$country = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['CountryCode']); 
 @$dob_d = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['birthday_day']); 
 @$dob_m = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['birthday_month']); 
 @$dob_y = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['birthday_year']); 
 @$date_of_reg = ist_time();
 $query = "INSERT INTO `CmUser` (`UserID`, `Fname`, `Lname`, `Email`, `Pass`, `Gender`, `Country`, `DOB_D`, `DOB_M`, `DOB_Y`, `Date_Of_Reg`) VALUES (NULL, '$fname', '$lname', '$email', '$pass', '$gender', '$country', $dob_d, $dob_m, $dob_y, '$date_of_reg');";  

 function NewUser() {
   global $query;
   $res = query($query); 
   if($res) { 
    echo "YOUR REGISTRATION IS COMPLETED..."; } else {
    echo "Error in Regisrtation ".$res; }
 }

function SignUp() {
  global $con;
  global $email;
  global $pass;
  if(!empty($email)) //checking the 'email' name which is from Sign-Up.html, is it empty or have some text 
   {
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM CmUser WHERE Email = '$email';");
    if(!$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error())) {
      newuser(); } 
     else { echo "SORRY...YOU ARE ALREADY REGISTERED USER..."; }
  }
}
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   SignUp();
 }

?>
```

I think the problem may be here :

```
 $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM CmUser WHERE Email = '$email';");
    if(!$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error())) {
      newuser(); } 
     else { echo "SORRY...YOU ARE ALREADY REGISTERED USER..."; }
```

Comment: I don't see any `mysqli_query($query)` statement to run insert query in your code!!

Comment: i have created a function **query()** in connect.php which handle this task

Comment: show your query function!

Comment: something might be wrong when sending query to query function. Try to declare your insert query in your query function don't send parameter to check whether problem is there or not.

Comment: that is already mentioned above, please refer to the connect.php

Comment: maybe your password in not 'root' try null in password `$password = ""; `

Comment: if userId is primary key it cannot be null and date_of_reg should be 'date_of_reg' because your is_time is returning date string

Comment: thanks bro it solved, after writing '$date_of_reg' instead of $date_of_reg and my time format was aslo incorrect , it should be in yyyy-mm-dd h:i:s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value `$date_of_reg` must be between single quotes in the query. Also, the semicolon is not mandatory:

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO `CmUser` (`UserID`, `Fname`, `Lname`, `Email`, `Pass`, `Gender`, `Country`, `DOB_D`, `DOB_M`, `DOB_Y`, `Date_Of_Reg`) VALUES (NULL, '$fname', '$lname', '$email', '$pass', '$gender', '$country', $dob_d, $dob_m, $dob_y, '$date_of_reg')";
```